# WSO2 log4j and elasticsearch: all carbon apps freeze

Tags: elasticsearch, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I've noticed a very strange behavior in my wso2 apps ( esb 4.9, AM 1.10 and GREG 5.0.0) 
Every single time the elasticsearch/logstash is stopped all the carbon apps freeze.
They become completely unresponsive and the only way to stop them is send a kill -9

My conf is pretty standard (see below) so I was wondering if I'm missing something or if someone else noticed the same issue.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY,tcp

log4j.appender.tcp=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.tcp.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.tcp.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c} – %x %m%n
log4j.appender.tcp.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D[%T]
log4j.appender.tcp.Port=6000
log4j.appender.tcp.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.tcp.ReconnectionDelay=10000
log4j.appender.tcp.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.tcp.Application=esb500wso2carbon
```

Answer (score 0):

What says the documentation :

> Logging events are automatically buffered by the native TCP
>   implementation. This means that if the link to server is slow but
>   still faster than the rate of (log) event production by the client,
>   the client will not be affected by the slow network connection.
>   However, if the network connection is slower then the rate of event
>   production, then the client can only progress at the network rate. In
>   particular, if the network link to the the server is down, the client
>   will be blocked.
>
> On the other hand, if the network link is up, but the
>   server is down, the client will not be blocked when making log
>   requests but the log events will be lost due to server unavailability.

But in my case, even when the "server is down", the client is blocked sometimes because many java threads are blocked on the same lock object

Have a look to JMSAppender or AsyncAppender

Answer (score 0):

According to WS02 is a bug.
It doesn't affect version 5.x
The suggested workaround, successfully tested, is to use filebeat instead :(
Not ideal, but it works